How to setup HDFS with Geoserver?
I want to test the performance of HDFS with geospatial data. So I setup HDFS but unable to fetch the data from HDFS and give it to Geoserver. Is there any way to fetch the data from HDFS and give it to Geoserver?
I tried Geowave and Geomesa but whenever I put the jar files of them in Geoserver, Geoserver would crash. I checked the compatibility of both with Geoserver and used the correct version.

Could you clarify the type of data you have in HDFS, the steps you followed to install the jars into geoserver, and the error messages and stack traces you are getting from geoserver?

I have TIF file in my hdfs. I have to give the path of the file in hdfs to the geoserver

First of all, I installed the jars of geomesa which are present in the geomesa-fs_2.12-5.0.0/dist/gs-plugins/geomesa-fs-gs-plugin_2.12-5.0.0-install.tar.gz directory into GeoServer geoserver-2.24.2-bin/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib then when I run the GeoServer from bin, I see the web app of GeoServer in localhost:8080 as 504 error.

To get the GeoMesa FileSystemDataStore working in GeoServer, follow the install instructions in the official documentation here. From your comment, it looks like you missed the second step of installing Hadoop jars.
However, GeoMesa is a vector store and doesn't support TIF files, so you will need to use a different technology stack.

Do you know any other way of connecting HDFS to GeoServer? And do you know how to access file path in HDFS or any other way to extract data from HDFS and use it?
